# Finding the equation of motion, or position vector? Vector Calculus

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]

I have a [Ferris wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ0NY.png) as on the link, and point A has an equation of motion, also on the diagram "r(t)". The question asks to find the position vector of B at time t, where the radii of both the wheels are the same and the distance between the centre point X is the same for both wheels. It appears like A and B will always have the same i axis number but the opposite signs, but how do I find out the correlation between the j?

Would I just use the equation of A, change the signs of the few numbers to derive the position vector of B, but if I do that, how can I check, whether or not the answer is right?

The exact question states about the diagram:

"State the position vector of Point B at time t minutes."

Thanks

Comment: Hint: You have $(A+B)/2 = X$, which is always stationary.

Comment: What does this mean, can you explain it, is it the position of X? How can this help, a little more elaboration will be helpful?

Comment: The position vectors of $A$ and $B$ must average to the position vector of $X = 0i + 35j$

Comment: This is now the third time you’ve posted essentially the same question.